# How to click a link with Tag name <a class </a> using Java in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I have below HTML code, where I have different <'li' class> tags under the <'ul'> tag. Within the <'li'> class tag, I will have tag  which needs to be clicked. These are results of some search in webpage, where all the items will be displayed as a list with pagination.

I need to verify if this  exist? and if it exists in 3 or 4th Index on the page, I need to click that link. Please let me know how I can get all these items into array and loop them and click any product available at random index.

```html
<ul id ="e1ResultsList">

<li class="e1ListingItem e1GrayShadow e1WhiteGradient e1ListingItemShow">
<div class="ribbon e1Hidden">
<div class="banner">
<div class="text">High Offer</div>
</div>
</div>

<span class="e1ListingImages">
<a class="`jsListingURL`" `href`="/event?`eventid`=7844">
<div class="e1SellerLogo e1Hidden"></div>
</span>
<span class="e1ListingDetails">
<div class="e1ListingTitle">
<a class="jsListingURL e1ListingTitleLink" href="/event?`eventid`=7844">vehicles and buses</a>
</div>

<span id="7844" class="" style="width: 100%;">enter code here
<div class="e1EventDetails">
<span class="e1EventInfo">
<div class="e1EventDescription">
<div class="e1EventID">
<div class="e1ListingCount">
<div class="e1ClosingDate">
<div class="e1EventHighlights">
</span>
</div>
</span>
</span>
</li>

<li class="e1ListingItem e1GrayShadow e1WhiteGradient e1ListingItemShow">
<div class="ribbon e1Hidden">
<span class="e1ListingImages">
<span class="e1ListingDetails">
<div class="e1ListingTitle">
<span id="7846" class="" style="width: 100%;">
</span>
</li>

<li class="e1ListingItem e1GrayShadow e1WhiteGradient e1ListingItemShow">
<div class="ribbon ribbon-white">
<span class="e1ListingImages">
<span class="e1ListingDetails">
<div class="e1ListingTitle">
<a class="jsListingURL e1ListingTitleLink" href="/listing?listingid=310786">2009 International 9200i Truck Tractor</a>
</div>
<span class="e1ListingInfo">
<span id="310786" class="e1ListingOffer" data-lastupdated="1430388219706">
</span>
</li>

<li class="e1ListingItem e1GrayShadow e1WhiteGradient e1ListingItemShow">
<div class="ribbon e1Hidden">
<span class="e1ListingImages">
<span class="e1ListingDetails">
<div class="e1ListingTitle">
<a class="jsListingURL e1ListingTitleLink" href="/listing?listingid=312207">2009 Mack CXU613 Vision Truck Tractor</a>
</div>
<span class="e1ListingInfo">
<span id="312207" class="e1ListingOffer" data-lastupdated="1430388219706">
</span>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Element element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.e1ListingItem a.jsListingURL")); if (element != null){}else{};

Comment: Thanks degr, can u explain in detail, my scenario is I have 15 products returned when searched, now I have to click 4th product in the list. The issue is the link which I need to click and links which I shouldn't click both have ""jsListingURL e1ListingTitleLink". However, the href changes.. can u please let me know how to handle this. Thanks!

Comment: you have difficult html structure. I think there is enough info for selection. Also you can use your span with id identifiers, and 'nth-child' selector. Read this article http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 1):

You could get a List of the 'a' tag WebElements on the page using the following:

```
List<WebElement> aTagsList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

You can then iterate over aTagsList as needed.

Edit:
To click the 4th 'a' tag WebElement in aTagsList, you can use the following:

```
WebElement requiredElement = aTagsList.get(4);
requiredElement.click();
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I was able to click the element but, I'm still seeing some issues. Is it possible to write condition to check even the tag "href="/listing?listingid" while getting the aTagsLIst? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the 4:th item you want to press?

If not, you have to know what you want to click. Either it is depending on the text or the "listingid".

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='310786']"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a:(*'2009 International 9200i Truck Tractor'*)")); );
```

Comment: Its not always the 4th element, also I shouldn't depend on the listing id, because it will change dynamically. I should click only if <a class="jsListingURL e1ListingTitleLink" href="/listing? is available anywhere on the page.

Comment: It doesnt seem as it is dynamicly changed. It looks like it is an id in a database. So the same name gets same id. 

So you should just click any link not a specific. That changes the question completly.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong, its not dynamically changing, but I have identified solution based on your previous answer :) Thanks

Comment: I have used below code to click required listing and looped it .                       List <WebElement> listings = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/listing?listingid']"));
    
    for (int i=0; i < listings.size(); i++) {
    
    
    WebElement requiredlisting = listings.get(i);
    requiredlisting.click();
      
    }

Comment: Now it seems as you click on all of them. So if I understand you correct it doesnt mather which link you click, it only needs to be a link in your search?

Comment: Yes Andreas. It doesn't matter which link I click, It needs to be a link with href=/listing?listingid.